# I need gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit (>=3.8)?

Tags: gambas3

Please help me. I need gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit (>=3.8) very badly! It is required by Estru3D software for installation. I have installed gambas3-gb-qt5-webkit_3.8.4-2ubuntu3_amd64, but Estru3d won't recognize it at all!! I can't find that file anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

Go into Ubuntu's "Software Sources" options and check the box to enable the "xenial-proposed" or "proposed software updates" repository. (version 3.8.4-2ubuntu2 of the package should be available in there)

Then open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit
```

Let us know if that works or if you have further questions.

Comment: Still nothing! I did all that and the result is : E: gambas3-gb-qt4-webkit  package not found.